# Error in Run Script

Tags: swift, xcode, runtime

I have a run time show this error on `Run Custom Shell Script on Build and Install Actor Core`. See the attached screenshots. Please, can anyone help solve this error?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have missed your attached image.

Comment: Can you build other projects?